# Multiplying odd numbers in a vector

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and I need to multiply odd numbers (by two) of the following vector:

`x<-c(1:20)`

I tried with this:
`x2<-c[lapply(x,"%%",2*2)==1]`

But something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base r, we can try

```
ifelse(x %% 2 != 0, x * 2, x)
> [1]  2  2  6  4 10  6 14  8 18 10 22 12 26 14 30 16 34 18 38 20
```

Answer (score 3):

For a vector like your example comprised of consecutive integers, we can use recycling

```
x * c(2,1)
##[1]  2  2  6  4 10  6 14  8 18 10 22 12 26 14 30 16 34 18 38 20
```

More generally, we can do

```
x * (x%%2 + 1L)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could find out the indices which are odd and multiply them by 2.

```
inds <- as.logical(x %% 2)
x[inds] <- x[inds] * 2
x
#[1]  2  2  6  4 10  6 14  8 18 10 22 12 26 14 30 16 34 18 38 20
```